# Is there any information in the public domain about the limits of technology cooperation between Russia and China?

Tags: russian-federation, china, technology

> Putin, who heads the world's biggest nuclear power, said military
> cooperation between Moscow and Beijing was increasing and focused on
> high-tech areas that would ensure strategic security. Advertisement ·
> Scroll to continue
>
> "Of course, our cooperation, our contacts in the military and
> military-technical sphere are also becoming increasingly important, as
> for military-technical cooperation, here, of course, our work in
> high-tech spheres comes first," Putin said.
>
> "I mean space, including high-orbit groupings, I also mean modern and
> promising weapons which will certainly ensure the strategic security
> of both Russia and the People's Republic of China."

https://www.reuters.com/world/putin-lauds-russias-high-tech-military-cooperation-with-china-2023-11-08/

> China and Russia are deepening cooperation on a key atomic technology
> that has Pentagon planners on edge because of its potential to upset
> the global balance of nuclear weapons.

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-03-22/china-russia-deepen-nuclear-concord-that-has-pentagon-on-edge

Is there any information in the public domain about the limits of technology cooperation between Russia and China? They mention cooperation between the two countries in military technology, but knowing there are existing sanctions against Russia for its war in Ukraine, I was wondering if there were limitation from the Chinese side about what technology they're not willing to share to avoid U.S. sanctions being imposed on them by the U.S. I am guessing nuclear technology is off-limit. Although an article on Bloomberg mention cooperation in civilian nuclear technology.